# Excel VBA: Create list of subfolders and files within source folder

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to list all files in a host folder and it's sub folders. The code works great but, do you know how I can update the code to also list some the file attributes.

```
Sub file_list()

Call ListFilesInFolder("W:\ISO 9001\INTEGRATED_PLANNING\", True)

End Sub

Sub ListFilesInFolder(ByVal SourceFolderName As String, ByVal IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)

Dim FSO As Object
Dim SourceFolder As Object
Dim SubFolder As Object
Dim FileItem As Object
Dim r As Long
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set SourceFolder = FSO.getFolder(SourceFolderName)
r = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files

  Cells(r, 1).Formula = FileItem.Name
  r = r + 1
  X = SourceFolder.Path
Next FileItem
If IncludeSubfolders Then
  For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.Subfolders
    ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True
  Next SubFolder
End If

Set FileItem = Nothing
Set SourceFolder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub

Function GetFileOwner(ByVal FilePath As String, ByVal FileName As String)

Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFolderItem As Object
Dim objShell As Object
FileName = StrConv(FileName, vbUnicode)
FilePath = StrConv(FilePath, vbUnicode)
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(StrConv(FilePath, vbFromUnicode))
If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
  Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(StrConv(FileName, vbFromUnicode))
End If
If Not objFolderItem Is Nothing Then
  GetFileOwner = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 8)
Else
  GetFileOwner = ""
End If
Set objShell = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objFolderItem = Nothing

End Function
```

What I would really like to see is;

Column A = Host folder/subfolder

Column B = File name

Column C = hyperlink to file

Is this possible?

I do have a code that created hyperlinks but, I do not know how to add to the existing code.

```
Sub startIt()

  Dim FileSystem As Object
  Dim HostFolder As String

  HostFolder = "W:\ISO 9001\INTEGRATED_PLANNING\"

  Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

End Sub

Sub DoFolder(Folder)

  Dim SubFolder
  For Each SubFolder In Folder.Subfolders
    DoFolder SubFolder
  Next

  i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  Dim File
  For Each File In Folder.Files
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(i, 1), Address:= _
        File.Path, TextToDisplay:=File.Name
    i = i + 1

  Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the list of properties that the `File` Object supports here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ft05taf(v=vs.84).aspx

So you can enhance your code, where it is taking the `.Name` property and putting that in a cell formula, to do something similar with other properties, such as the `.Type` of the file.

```
For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
  Cells(r, 1).Formula = FileItem.Name
  Cells(r, 2).Value = FileItem.Type
  ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(r, 3), Address:= _
    FileItem.Path, TextToDisplay:=FileItem.Name 
  r = r + 1
  X = SourceFolder.Path
Next FileItem
```

n.b. I've used Value instead of Formula, but in this case the result will be the same.

In a similar manner, you can add another `Cells(r, 3).Value =` line to set the value of cell in the current row `r` and column `3` to whatever your hyperlink is.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little script for this purpose to my colleague for a time ago...

See my code below:

```
Sub FolderNames()
'Written by Daniel Elmnas Last update 2016-02-17
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim xPath As String
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim fso As Object, j As Long, folder1 As Object
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Choose the folder"
    .Show
End With
On Error Resume Next
xPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"
Application.Workbooks.Add
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
xWs.Cells(1, 1).Value = xPath
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = Array("Subfolder", "Hostfolder", "Filename", "Date Created", "Date Last Modified")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder1 = fso.getFolder(xPath)
getSubFolder folder1
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 5).Interior.Color = 65535
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 5).EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub getSubFolder(ByRef prntfld As Object)
Dim SubFolder As Object
Dim subfld As Object
Dim xRow As Long
For Each SubFolder In prntfld.SubFolders
    xRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    Cells(xRow, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = Array(SubFolder.Path, Left(SubFolder.Path, InStrRev(SubFolder.Path, "\")), SubFolder.Name, SubFolder.DateCreated, SubFolder.DateLastModified)
Next SubFolder
For Each subfld In prntfld.SubFolders
    getSubFolder subfld
Next subfld
End Sub
```

Here is the result:
[image]

You can modify it a bit though.

If you example dont want to use a window-dialog and instead use 
"W:\ISO 9001\INTEGRATED_PLANNING\"

Cheers!